# how to get the appended value of input using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just want to ask to those master in jquery..

I have ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL",
    data: {
        DATA: DATA
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        //action
    },
    success: function(result){
        $('.className').html(result);
    }
});
```

It already append the `<input type="hidden" class="ClassName" value="1">`

I try to use

```
$('.btnClick').on('click',function(){ $('.ClassName').val() }
```

but still it didn't get the appended input hidden value
is there someone to help me?

Comment: What you want exactly.... ???

Comment: Hey, I answered this exact question yesterday. Then it got deleted immediately :(. plus. Try using the notation of `$(document).on('click', '.btnClick', funtion...)`. Otherwise you are hooking up only with already existing elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care of the cases. `className` is not the same as `ClassName`. Also, an `input` does not have HTML inside, so calling `html` on it should not work, use `val` instead.

```
$('.className').html(result);
```

Should be

```
$('.ClassName').val(result);
```

Also, take care with the selectors. If you use the class name as a selector and you have multiple input fields with the same class name, the ajax bit will update all fields at once. Later, when you try to retrieve the value like you do, it will show only the value of the first one.

If you only plan on having one input with that class name, then you should probably use an id instead of a class, to avoid future confusions.

```
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myid" class="myclass" value="1">
```

Setting the value ...

```
$('#myid').val(result);
```

Getting the value ...

```
thevalue = $('#myid').val();
```